# How to change the caption "Table" to a greek word?

Tags: tables, longtable, greek

I want to change the caption "Table" to "Πίνακας". So, the greek word is "Πίνακας".
I have tried many commands but nothing works.

I have also tried with the package `babel` but it does not work.

When I use `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Πίνακας}` the result is:

```
\begin{longtable}{c c c c | c c c c}    
    \caption{\textit{Upper bounds on M with q=3}} \\ [-2ex]
    \hline
    Sr no. & \textit{N} & \textit{M} & \textit{E(f$ _{NOD} $)}& Sr no. & \textit{N} & \textit{M} & \textit{E(f$ _{NOD} $)}\\ 
    \hline
    1        &6    &5    &2   &17       &54   &25     &0\\
    2        &9    &4    &0   &18       &57   &29     &2\\
    3       &12    &7    &2   &19       &60   &31     &2\\
    4       &15    &8    &2   &20      &63   &31     &0\\
    5       &18    &7    &0   &21       &66   &34     &2\\
    6       &21   &11    &2   &22       &69   &35     &2\\
    7       &24   &13    &2   &23      &72   &34     &0\\
    8       &27   &13    &0   &24       &75   &38     &2\\
    9      &30   &16    &2   &25       &78   &40     &2\\
    10       &33   &17    &2   &26       &81   &40     &0\\
    11       &36   &16    &0   &27       &84   &43     &2\\
    12       &39   &20    &2   &28       &87   &44     &2\\
    13       &42   &22    &2   &29       &90   &43     &0\\
    14       &45   &22    &0   &30       &93   &47     &2\\
    15      &48   &25    &2   &31       &96   &49     &2 \\
    16     &51  &26    &2   &32       &99   &49     &0\\
    \hline 
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

When I use `\renewcommand{\tablename}{ΠΙΝΑΚΑΣ}` the result is:
[image]

I think that the problem is about lowercase and uppercase.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide the code which produces your first image as a minimal *working* example? Which packages do you use for that, which documentclass? Do you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Comment: For the future: When you insert a code block don't use the high ticks to mark it (that is inline code), but mark the whole block (using your mouse) and hit the `{}`-like icon in the editor, that marks it as code (or start every line with 4 spaces). Also: The code you have provided is not a MWE. A MWE begins at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` and loads every package which is necessary to make it compilable.

Comment: My document class is harvard-thesis. I use LaTex.

Comment: Sorry, but without a pointer to the class you are using, together with a minimal example of code, it's impossible to guess what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following works:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[main=english,greek]{babel}

\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand*{\tablename}{\textbf{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Πίνακας}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        test&test
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{test}
    \label{tab:test}
\end{table}
\begin{longtable}{c c c c | c c c c}    
    \caption{\textit{Upper bounds on M with q=3}} \\ [-2ex]
    \hline
    Sr no. & \textit{N} & \textit{M} & \textit{E(f$ _{NOD} $)}& Sr no. & \textit{N} & \textit{M} & \textit{E(f$ _{NOD} $)}\\ 
    \hline
    1        &6    &5    &2   &17       &54   &25     &0\\
    2        &9    &4    &0   &18       &57   &29     &2\\
    3       &12    &7    &2   &19       &60   &31     &2\\
    4       &15    &8    &2   &20      &63   &31     &0\\
    5       &18    &7    &0   &21       &66   &34     &2\\
    6       &21   &11    &2   &22       &69   &35     &2\\
    7       &24   &13    &2   &23      &72   &34     &0\\
    8       &27   &13    &0   &24       &75   &38     &2\\
    9      &30   &16    &2   &25       &78   &40     &2\\
    10       &33   &17    &2   &26       &81   &40     &0\\
    11       &36   &16    &0   &27       &84   &43     &2\\
    12       &39   &20    &2   &28       &87   &44     &2\\
    13       &42   &22    &2   &29       &90   &43     &0\\
    14       &45   &22    &0   &30       &93   &47     &2\\
    15      &48   &25    &2   &31       &96   &49     &2 \\
    16     &51  &26    &2   &32       &99   &49     &0\\
    \hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is still not working on me! The result is the same as the second picture in my question!

Comment: Do you have any idea why it does not work on me?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis do you compile it with `pdflatex`?

Comment: No @MichaelFraiman. I complile it with `xeLaTex`.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman when I compile it with pdfLaTex the log is:

* XeTeX is required to compile this document. \RequireXeTeX

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis do you load a system font or use Computer Modern?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I have not load any system font.  So, I use Computer Modern, Even if I tried to use another font, it did not work!

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis do you want me to post an answer where I use system font? This is quite resonable, because you use `XeLaTeX`

Comment: @MichaelFraiman yes of course! Post your answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61224/discussion-between-vassilis-chasiotis-and-michael-fraiman).

Answer (score 1):

As the OP mentioned, s/he uses `XeLaTeX`, so a solution using `polyglossia` package is the following (based on the answer by @Skillmon).

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage[main=english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Times New Roman}

\addto\captionsenglish{
 \renewcommand*{\tablename}{\textbf{Πίνακας}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
     test&test
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{test}
 \label{tab:test}
\end{table}
\begin{longtable}{c c c c | c c c c}    
 \caption{\textit{Upper bounds on M with q=3}} \\ [-2ex]
 \hline
 Sr no. & \textit{N} & \textit{M} & \textit{E(f$ _{NOD} $)}& Sr no. & \textit{N} & \textit{M} & \textit{E(f$ _{NOD} $)}\\ 
 \hline
 1        &6    &5    &2   &17       &54   &25     &0\\
 2        &9    &4    &0   &18       &57   &29     &2\\
 3       &12    &7    &2   &19       &60   &31     &2\\
 4       &15    &8    &2   &20      &63   &31     &0\\
 5       &18    &7    &0   &21       &66   &34     &2\\
 6       &21   &11    &2   &22       &69   &35     &2\\
 7       &24   &13    &2   &23      &72   &34     &0\\
 8       &27   &13    &0   &24       &75   &38     &2\\
 9      &30   &16    &2   &25       &78   &40     &2\\
 10       &33   &17    &2   &26       &81   &40     &0\\
 11       &36   &16    &0   &27       &84   &43     &2\\
 12       &39   &20    &2   &28       &87   &44     &2\\
 13       &42   &22    &2   &29       &90   &43     &0\\
 14       &45   &22    &0   &30       &93   &47     &2\\
 15      &48   &25    &2   &31       &96   &49     &2 \\
 16     &51  &26    &2   &32       &99   &49     &0\\
 \hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot understand what I am doing wrong, but it does not work!
The result is just the first letter ( Π ), but not the whole word (Πίνακας). Note that the file is compiled without errors.

Comment: Have you tried this code in a separate file?

Comment: I am using the harvard-thesis for my PhD thesis. You can download it here: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/harvard-phd

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis does changing the class in **my** code result in such beaviour?